# In CSS, selecting parent <label> for an <input> that is selected

Tags: css, reactjs

Edit: apparently cant use <> braces  or it hides names?...

I've seen a few variations of this question asked, however none of what I found fits my particular issue, which I think is a simple issue. I am creating the following radio button group in react:

```
    const myOptions = ["YTD", "Week", "Month", "Pre AS", "Post AS"]
    const myButtons =
        <form>
            <div className="radio-group">
                {myOptions.map((d, i) => {
                    return (
                        <label>
                            <input
                                type={"radio"}
                                value={myOptions[i]}
                                checked={timeframeNew === myOptions[i]}
                                onChange={this.handleTimeframeNewChange}
                            />
                            <span>{myOptions[i]}</span>
                        </label>
                    )
                })}
            </div>
        </form>;
```

and here is my current CSS for styling the buttons to look nice...

```
input[type=radio] { 
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}

label {
  color: #333;
  background: #EEE;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  color: red;
  background: #333;
}

label + input[type=radio] + label {
  border-left: solid 2px blue;
}

.radio-group {
  border: solid 2px green;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Unfortunately, the CSS is not working as intended. In particular, the following selection - **input[type=radio]:checked + label** does not work because there is no *label* immediately after an *input*. The only way so far I have been able to successfully get my react onChange handler function to work is by putting the input inside of the label, like this, and then returning the *label* in each .map loop.

*Since the return needs to be a single element, if I want to take the  out of the *label*, I would need to then include them both in a *div* or a *span*, and for some reason doing so breaks my onChange handler...

So my question is, **how how how** can I, in CSS, grab the *label* that corresponds to the clicked *input*. I would like to change the entire label's color and background when it is / isn't clicked, so selecting the span does not help (since that only changes the texts color/background, not the whole label.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Since the return needs to be a single element, if I want to take the out of the label, I would need to then include them both in a div or a span, and for some reason doing so breaks my onChange handler...

You can use `<React.Fragment> <input /> <span /> </ReactFragment>` to return multiple elements without rendering them inside a div or span

Comment: I will try this, but I am worried it will still break the functionality of the buttons. I'm not sure why, but having the input **not** inside the label is giving me a problem...

Comment: oh, sorry! understood the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

CSS can select child and sibling elements, but not parent elements. I often hide default radio buttons and checkboxes and create my own, like this:

```css
.button-group{
  font-size:0; /*Prevents a space from occuring between buttons*/
}
.button-group input{
  position:absolute; 
  visibility:hidden; /* display:none causes some browsers to ignore the input altogether */
}
.button-group input+span{
  display:inline-block;
  line-height:20px;
  font-size:1rem;
  vertical-align:top;
  padding:0 10px;
  color:#000;
  border-left:1px solid #a00;
}
.button-group label:first-child input+span{
  border-radius:10px 0 0 10px;
  border-left:0;
}
.button-group label:last-child input+span{
  border-radius:0 10px 10px 0;
}
.button-group input:not(:checked)+span{
  background-color:#faa;
}
.button-group input:not(:checked)+span:hover{
  background-color:#f66;
}
input[type=radio]:checked+span{
  background-color:#f33;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-group">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="myfield" />
    <span>Option 1</span>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="myfield" />
    <span>Option 2</span>
  </label>

  <label>
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="myfield" />
    <span>Option 3</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like for the buttons to be connected as a "radio button group", which is part of the reason why i'd like to select the labels rather than the spans.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "radio button group". Could you provide an example or a screenshot?

Comment: actually I take that back, I don't mind the buttons not being connected

Comment: I have edited my post to create what I think you mean by "button group".

Comment: @RobertAKARobin Can I ask you why you don't simply use `display:none` on your input ? (instead of all the `position, visibility, width, etc...`

Comment: On some browsers it causes the input's value to not be recognized at all. Very frustrating.

Comment: @RobertAKARobin Thanks, I didn't know that !

Answer (score 2):

There is a CSS only way to do this with the [:has-selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

Example:

```html
<label>
  Option 1
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="1" />
</label>

<label>
  Option 2
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="2" />
</label>
```

```css
label:has(input:checked) {
  background: red;
}
```